# Acumatica tab item order

Tags: acumatica

It seems like this should be simple, but how do I change the order of tab items in a set of tabs on a customized Acumatica web page? I created a new tab item and moved it to the first tab item when customizing it, and it's also the first tab item in the .aspx if I view it. However, if I export and publish within a package, it's the last tab item shown instead of the first.

This is 2017 R2.

Comment: Do you have other customizations? Does the published ASPX file in the CstPublished folder have the tab in the correct spot?

Comment: I don't do this much (create/move tabs) but I just rebuilt our customization to move our tabs. Its easy if you just use the edit aspx option and paste the tab where you want it and save to DB. You could just try this with an empty tab to see the project.xml it creates to see if it helps and just update your project.xml with the PXTabItem tags related to the text of the standard tabs. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: There are additional customizations besides the tab ordering included, yes. The source .aspx has the tab in the correct order.  In the published folder it is in the wrong position.